# $f_n(x) \rightharpoonup0$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ where $f_n(x) = f(-x+n^3)$

Tags: lp-spaces, weak-convergence, sequence-of-function

Let $f \in C_c^0(\mathbb{R})$ be a continuous function with compact support. Is it true that

1. $f_n(x)=f(-x+n^3)\rightharpoonup0$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$?
2. $f_n(x)=f(x+\frac{1}{e^n})\rightharpoonup0$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

I know that in order to determine if a sequence $f_n$ in $L^p$ weakly converges to a function $f$ in $L^p$ I have to show if $$\int f_n(x)g(x)dx \longrightarrow \int f(x)g(x) dx \quad \forall g\in L^{p'}$$

Is it true that, for case 1., if I take $f_n(x)= \chi_{[-n,n]}*\rho_{\epsilon}$ I obtain a continuous function with compact support and
$\int f_n(x)g(x)dx \not \longrightarrow 0 \quad \forall g\in L^{p'}$ because the translation by $n^3$ doesn't affect the behaviour at infinity?

I don't understand what are the differences between the two cases 1. and 2. and how to deal with translations.

Have you any hint?

Comment: You can't take $f_n(x)= \chi_{[-n,n]}*\rho_{\epsilon}$. You need to specify your $f$, and then your $f_n$ is defined as its translation.

Comment: 2. Is false; in fact, $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1$. The difference between the two cases is that in 1., the translation gets larger and large, while in 2., it gets smaller and smaller.

Comment: @Sambo it's true, I have to find my $f$ first. So, how can I determine if $<f_n,g> \rightharpoonup 0 \forall g \in L^{\infty}$? And for 2. why $f_n \rightarrow f$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Hints$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$

For question 1: since $L^{1'}(\R) = L^{\infty}(\R)$, we can take $g \equiv 1$ in $L^{\infty}(\R)$. Then remark that:
$$
\int f_n \cdot g = \int f_n = \int f
$$

For question 2: what function does $(f_n)_n$ converge pointwise to? What do the norms of the $f_n$ converge to?

Comment: $(f_n)_n \rightarrow f(x)$ and the $\lvert\rvert f_n \lvert\rvert_1 = \lvert\rvert f \lvert\rvert_1$. And then I apply again $g \equiv 1 \in L^{\infty}$ to obtain that the sequence does not converge to zero. Is it right?

Comment: I suppose that is a quicker way to show it. My idea is that these two facts about the $(f_n)_n$ imply that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.